# Prolog: compare three lists, 1st element of list1 to last element of list2 AND second to last element of list3

Tags: prolog

Write a PROLOG program (i.e., set of predicates) that implements the following function. The program should compare three lists and determine if the first element of the first list is the same as both the last element of the second list and the second to last element of the third list. Call the main predicate:  compare(List1, List2, List3).

I went ahead and wrote separate codes for the two separate conditions, which works on its own. 
1. 1st item of List1 equals last item of List2.
2. 1st item of List1 equals second to last item of List3.

Now I'm having trouble combining the codes to work together.  My train of thought is that condition 1 and condition 2 have to be met separately before the overall condition is met.  So somehow I have to run the code for condition 1 and condition 2 on its own but in the same program??  And if both of those return true then I can have something else that says my conditions are met.

```
compare(List1,List2,List3):- last(true), secondLast(true).
```

Condition1:

```
last([HeadList1|RestList1],[HeadList1]).
last([HeadList1|RestList1],[HeadList2|RestList2]) :-
  last([HeadList1|RestList1],RestList2).
```

Condition2:

```
secondLast([HeadList1|RestList1],[HeadList1,RestList3]).
secondLast([HeadList1|RestList1],[HeadList3|RestList3]) :-
  secondLast([HeadList1|RestList1],RestList3).
```

What I'm expecting:

```
?- compare([2,8,9,1],[4,5,6,2],[1,2,3]).
yes

?- compare([a,b,c,d,k],[a,c,f,e],[a,s]).
no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SWI, you can use `last/2` and the definition of `secondTast/2` [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497345/prolog-return-second-to-last-list-element):

```
secondLast([X,_], X).
secondLast([_|T], X) :- secondLast(T, X).

my_compare([H|_],L1,L2):-
    last(L1,H),
    secondLast(L2,H).

?- my_compare([2,8,9,1],[4,5,6,2],[1,2,3]).
true

?- my_compare([a,b,c,d,k],[a,c,f,e],[a,s]).
false
```

You can put a cut to avoid the solution false in the first query. This is a first solution, you can get super fancy and use for instance `reverse/2` and other predicates to find another solution (but maybe slower).

Comment: Thank you, I understand this solution because it's rudimentary and is on par with my beginner's knowledge of prolog.  

I see that the secondLast predicate is the same structure as the code i posted in the OP, however a lot more streamline and simplified.

What I don't understand is how does the last(L1,H) predicate work on its own without a recursive call?

Comment: Oh, rereading your comments again, I just realized that "last()" is a predicate of its own.

Answer (score 1):

@damianodamiano suggests an implementation using `reverse/2` and I thought it might be interesting to see what it is.

```
mycompare([H|_], L2, L3) :-
    reverse(L2, [H|_]),
    reverse(L3, [_, H|_]).
```

`reverse/2` is somewhat more expensive than a list traversal, so this may not be the best way to solve the problem, I think it's worth seeing because it's fairly close to the question as stated and it demonstrates that this problem is solved really by unification and only unification. damianodamiano's solution has a similar property in that you are finding the first thing, `H` and then showing that `H` appears in other positions in the other two lists.

Now I have some miscellaneous feedback for you:

- You are right to believe that if you have two predicates, say `p1` and `p2`, you can combine them by doing `p1, p2`. In general, they are going to share variable bindings between them because what you are doing in programming in Prolog is *setting up a relationship between certain things*.

  This is also why singleton "warnings" are actually errors: they reveal cases where you believe there is a relationship, but where Prolog could tell that you didn't share the variable anywhere, so no relationship was established.
- Your variable names are really bad. If 99% of all your variable names are the same, you are going to get confused. It would be better to use `A` and `B` than `HeadList1` and `HeadList2`. If you must use names like these, simplify to `H1` and `H2`. When you see `[X|Y]`, you know X is a head of a list and `Y` is a list tail, you do not need to make that information part of the name. Focus on the content of the variable if you can, or the relationship you're trying to establish between the expressions that variable is a part of.
- Prolog predicates do **not** "return true." They can succeed or fail but they are not evaluated like functions: you cannot replace `mycompare(A,B,C)` with `true` just because `mycompare(A,B,C)` succeeds, you cannot assign a value to the result `R = mycompare(A,B,C)`, and you cannot nest predicates like `writeln(mycompare(A,B,C))`. So break this habit now so you don't confuse yourself further in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the much needed explanation and clarifications :).

Comment: @Hoang no problem, keep Prologing!